Browser extension shortcut failing
I have a cross browser, manifest v3, extension that can be toggled using cmd+period as a keyboard shortcut. This shortcut works intermittenlty, so I'm wondering if there any reserved command that uses cmd+period on some browsers, or on macs. Any idea?
 _execute_action: {
        suggested_key: {
          default: 'Ctrl+Period',
          mac: 'Command+Period',
        },
      },

Switching from "cmd+period" to other shortcuts fixes the issue probably, but I want to better understand why "cmd+period" fails.

It may be a bug in the browser.

I've encountered a similar issue, where gap failures will occur when the shortcuts registered by extension overlap with chrome's built-in shortcuts (I just haven't figured out the trigger conditions).
Check out the Chrome Shortcut List if you encounter this.
Apparently there is a shortcut in this list that is the same as “CMD+ period”.

